# i want to maximum 8 values show on click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that adds a new box to a list. How do I make it disappear after having exactly eight boxes visible?

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#added-more').click(function() {
      var paste = $('#copy li').clone();
      console.log(paste);
      $('#Compare-to-add').prepend(paste)
    })

  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="Compare-to-add">
  <div id="copy" style="display:none">
    <li><a href="#">Box</a>
    </li>
  </div>
  <li><a href="#">Box</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Box</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Box</a>
  </li>

  <p id="added-more">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
  </p>

</ul>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Baloch007/9jo8tka5/4/

Comment: Jsfiddle link are here **https://jsfiddle.net/Baloch007/9jo8tka5/4/**

Comment: add all relevant code to OP :)

Comment: You can use `$('#Compare-to-add li').length` to identify the number of `li`. Check this **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/9jo8tka5/9/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/9jo8tka5/5/)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#added-more').click(function() {
      var paste = $('#copy li').clone();
      console.log(paste);
      $('#Compare-to-add').prepend(paste)
      //following if condition has been added
      if ($("#Compare-to-add li:visible").size() == 8 )
      {
         $('#added-more').hide();
      }
    })
  });
```

Comment: i am very Thankful to you **gurvinder372**